# Django Haystack document=True, from a conceptual standpoint

Tags: django, django-haystack

So, I'm trying to wrap my mind around the concept of "`text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)`". From the documentation:

> Every SearchIndex requires there be one (and only one) field with document=True. This indicates to both Haystack and the search engine about which field is the primary field for searching within.

Since every example I see seems to just have this "thrown in" as a convention, how does "`text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)`" actually describe anything at all?

1. What field from the model is the engine choosing to search on primarily when using this convention?
2. Shouldn't there always be a `model_attr=desired_model_attr` in this `text` field, so the engine can actually know which model_attr is the primary field for searching on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some further investigation, I think I understand - answering my own question for others who may have this same question.

I believe that my confusion is mostly related to the use of `use_template=True` in the documentation. When you use a template, you don't need to set a `model_attr` in your index because you describe the document structure (and model fields you wish to search on) in your data template. So to answer my two questions:

1. Because you specify use_template=True, you must describe the model fields you want to search on in your data template. Don't set `use_template=True` if you intend to set a `model_attr`.
2. See above.